# Can my ISP detect what YouTube stream quality i play on my device

Tags: isp, streaming

I would like to know if there is a way that my ISP can detect the youtube stream quality I use on my device.

For Example-

When I watch youtube video in 360p resolution and I move to the 1080p resolution. Can my ISP detect that quality from their end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your ISP cannot see the "quality" of whatever YouTube videos you are watching. Everything is encrypted with [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS).

However, they can detect changes in terms of the bandwidth consumed. Example, streaming 360p then suddenly switching to 4k quality. Obviously, 4k takes a lot of bandwidth. They wouldn't see which videos you are viewing and the resolution of those videos, but they can see how much data you are consuming.

Comment: In other words bandwidth utilisation can be used to infer the resolution, but not with 100% accuracy.